# fetching a table with another tables "conditions"

Tags: postgresql, select, conditional-statements

I have two tables like this:

Table Name: `users`

```
emx  |   userid
---------------
1    |   1
2    |   2
```

and another table called `bodies`

```
id   |   emx   |   text
--------------------------
1    |   1     |   Hello
2    |   2     |   How are you?
```

As you can see, bodies table has `emx` which is id numbers of `users` table. Now, when i want to fetch message that contains `Hello` i just search it on `bodies` and get the `emx` numbers and after that i fetch users table with these emx numbers. So, i am doing 2 sql queries to find it.

So, all i want to do is make this happen in 1 SQL query.

I tried some queries which is not correct and also i tried JOIN too. No luck yet. I just want to fetch users table with message contains 'Hello' in bodies table.

Note: I am using PostgreSQL 9.1.3.

Any idea / help is appreciated.

Comment: You should show the SQL queries that you use. And the one you've tried that doesn't work.

Comment: I removed it but shortly it is `SELECT * FROM x INNER JOIN y ON a = b WHERE x.a = 1`. Inner Join caused this error. This is why i got the unexpected result. I will try answers (both you and vyegorov's).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do the join. I've left out the exact containment test.

```
SELECT users.userid 
FROM users JOIN bodies ON (users.emx = bodies.emx) 
WHERE ⌜true if bodies.text contains ?⌟
```

Comment: Man, it was a typo! How can i miss that. It worked - as supposed to be-

Answer (score 2):

1. Read docs on [how to join tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM).
2. Try this:

```sql
    SELECT u.emx, u.userid, b.id, b.text
      FROM bodies b
      JOIN users u USING (emx)
     WHERE b.text ~ 'Hello';
```